# p:uploadFile event not sent on first access to page

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a single page application where I update the view using includes like thus :

```
<ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/#{viewStateController.content}.xhtml" />
```

When I click on the menu link below :

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn_left" 
        title="IMPORT DE FICHIER de FORCAGE"
        actionListener="#{mainViewManager.importForcage()}"
        update="growl contentContainer" 
        partialSubmit="false">
                Import Fichier For&#231;age
</p:commandLink>
```

I update the include to a page showing an uploadFile component :

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8" > 
    <p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{forcageView.handleFileUpload}"
        mode="advanced" 
        auto="true"
        label="Télécharger un fichier"
        update="messages" 
        sizeLimit="5242880"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|txt)$/" 
        disabled="#{!forcageView.forcageActif}"/>

    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

When I click the upload button and select a file to upload, the event is not sent  to the managed bean.

If I click on the menu button a second time or navigate somewhere else and come back then it works correctly.

- Primefaces : 6.2
- JSF 2.2

Comment: Did it work in PF 6.1? And please create a [mcve]

Comment: And read all results of https://www.google.com/search?q=action+not+called+on+first+click+jsf

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't say. I have been using the 6.2 version for a while before using the uploadFile component. 
I only gave the version to give a more exhaustive picture.

Comment: Hi, reminder for the first comment below your question. [mcve]. I did not downvote (yet), but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Is your backing bean using ViewScoped?

Comment: @jpllosa Yes, the backing bean is ViewScoped